# How can I run a Views SQL query in PhpMyAdmin?

Tags: 7, views, database

i go to admin/structure/views/settings, check Show information and statistics about the view during live preview and then Show the SQL query checkbox that will appear below.

I have a field which is field_col the field type is Node reference  and the widget is a Select list.

this field can have only one value, and in its settings, it is set as to reference a content type named col. Also in the field settings, there is the following:

VIEWS - NODES THAT CAN BE REFERENCED
The list of nodes that can be referenced can provided by a view (Views module) using the "References" display type.
There a view is set, whose sql query is the below code:

```
SELECT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid
FROM 
{node} node
INNER JOIN {og_mm} og_mm_node ON node.nid = og_mm_node.etid AND og_mm_node.entity_type = 'node'
WHERE (( (og_mm_node.gid = '20' ) )AND(( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('col')) )))
ORDER BY node_title ASC
```

In the view, where in the live preview i get the results i want, the sql query looks like:

```
SELECT node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created, node_field_data_field_title.title AS node_field_data_field_title_title, field_data_field_it_ac_nr.field_it_ac_nr_value AS field_data_field_it_ac_nr_field_it_ac_nr_value, field_data_field_col.field_col_nid AS field_data_field_col_field_col_nid, field_data_field_t_year.field_t_year_value AS field_data_field_t_year_field_t_year_value, field_data_field_it_vlm.field_it_vlm_value AS field_data_field_it_vlm_field_it_vlm_value, field_data_field_it_cn.field_it_cn_value AS field_data_field_it_cn_field_it_cn_value, 'node' AS field_data_field_it_ac_nr_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_col_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_tak_node_entity_type
FROM 
node node
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_title field_data_field_title ON node.nid = field_data_field_title.entity_id AND field_data_field_title.entity_type = 'node'
LEFT JOIN node node_field_data_field_title ON field_data_field_title.field_title_nid = node_field_data_field_title.nid
LEFT JOIN og_mm og_mm_node ON node.nid = og_mm_node.etid AND og_mm_node.entity_type = 'node'
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_deleted field_data_field_deleted ON node.nid = field_data_field_deleted.entity_id AND field_data_field_deleted.field_deleted_value = '1'
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_it_ac_nr field_data_field_it_ac_nr ON node.nid = field_data_field_it_ac_nr.entity_id AND field_data_field_it_ac_nr.entity_type = 'node'
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_col field_data_field_col ON node.nid = field_data_field_col.entity_id AND field_data_field_col.entity_type = 'node'
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_t_year field_data_field_t_year ON node.nid = field_data_field_t_year.entity_id AND field_data_field_t_year.entity_type = 'node'
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_it_vlm field_data_field_it_vlm ON node.nid = field_data_field_it_vlm.entity_id AND field_data_field_it_vlm.entity_type = 'node'
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_it_cn field_data_field_it_cn ON node.nid = field_data_field_it_cn.entity_id AND field_data_field_it_cn.entity_type = 'node'
WHERE (( (og_mm_node.gid = '20' ) )AND(( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('product')) AND (field_data_field_deleted.field_deleted_value IS NULL ) )))
ORDER BY field_data_field_it_ac_nr_field_it_ac_nr_value ASC, field_data_field_col_field_col_nid ASC, field_data_field_t_year_field_t_year_value ASC, field_data_field_it_vlm_field_it_vlm_value ASC, field_data_field_it_cn_field_it_cn_value ASC
```

but it returns the node id of the node that is referenced, and not the value i need. How the two above should be made, combined, in order to get the results i want?

Answer (score 1):

Always use the API to load entity data; getting it directly from the database is not recommended.

Once you have your node IDs from the initial query:

```
$nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  foreach (field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_col') as $item) {
    // Do something with $item['value'], for example
  }
}
```

Comment: could you please elaborate on why getting it directly from the database is not recommended? I would like to see how a complete mysql query should look like in order to get the results the view returns also...

Comment: It's a standard development principle - program to the interface, not the implementation. If you tie your code to the underlying implementation, it'll break when that implementation changes. I would personally ignore what Views is doing, and make sure you're simply writing code that does what you want it to